# why tailwind compile the following classname that seems not intuitive?

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-3

I'm new to Tailwind , Im curios about why Tailwind compile the following class in an file input element:
`hover:file:bg-violet-100`
to
`.hover\:file\:bg-violet-100::file-selector-button:hover`

I thought it will compile it to
`.hover\:file\:bg-violet-100:hover::file-selector-button`
becaus it seems more intuitive

Similiarly , Tailwind compile the following class :
`file:hover:bg-violet-100`
to
`.file\:hover\:bg-violet-100:hover::file-selector-button`
which is not the class I thought :
`.file\:hover\:bg-violet-100::file-selector-button:hover`

Can anybody tell me why ? thank you ! I will realy appreciate if anybody can resolve my question.

I am trying understanding the compiliation order for pseudo-element in Tailwind.

Answer (score 0):

As per [the documentation on ordering of stacked modifiers](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#ordering-stacked-modifiers):

> When stacking modifiers, they are applied from the inside-out, like nested function calls:
>
> ```js
> // These modifiers:
> 'dark:group-hover:focus:opacity-100'
>
> // ...are applied like this:
> dark(groupHover(focus('opacity-100')))
> ```

Hence, for `hover:file:bg-violet-100`:

```
hover:file:bg-violet-100
                ↓
     hover:bg-violet-100::file-selector-button
                ↓
           bg-violet-100::file-selector-button:hover
```

and for `file:hover:bg-violet-100`:

```
file:hover:bg-violet-100
                ↓
      file:bg-violet-100:hover
                ↓
           bg-violet-100:hover::file-selector-button
```